# Oblivious transfer applications: how to apply?

Tags: oblivious-transfer

I have a basic question about the Homomorphic Encryption schemes, garbled circuits, Oblivious Transfer (OT), two-party computation, and multi-party computation. Specifically, I want to understand, how to apply these great techniques, or are these at the theoretical stage?

More specifically, are the OT schemes applied in real-world applications?

Can somebody point me to some good papers in which OT is applied to implement the application? This will help me understand how it can be applied?

Comment: I'm unable to point an application of OT with a business case. But in cryptography, including applied, there's no firm threshold between _theoretical_ and _applied_. It's about as messy as between _conjectured_ and _proven_.

Comment: You could look at the paper: [From Keys to Databases -- Real-World Applications of Secure Multi-Party Computation](https://ia.cr/2018/450)